# Flutter Emulator Error | Failed to find Platform SDK with path: platforms;android-R

Tags: android, flutter, android-fragments, sdk, android-gradle-plugin

i am compiling my app in IOS simulator it runs find and when i try to run it on android emulator or android phone it give me this error.
i already installed all SDKs but still i have this issue.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app_settings:compileDebugAidl'.
> Failed to find Platform SDK with path: platforms;android-R
```

i am posting screenshot of my build gradle file and sdk manager:
[build gradle file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82fs6.png)

[sdk tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1diLf.png)

Comment: do you get any problems in project structure?

Comment: Do you actually have the android SDK installed? After AS upgrades I've found things get lost - removing the packages and reinstalling them sometimes helps.

Answer (score 2):

```
    subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"

    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')

    afterEvaluate {project ->
        if (project.hasProperty("android") && project.property("android").compileSdkVersion.equals("android-R")) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion 30
            }
        }
    }
}
```